# ID based NPC system

Tags: entity-framework, xna, theory

I have a bunch of different npcs. They all have different properties and different AI, so I have made a separate class for each type, and derive it from a base class Entity. I want to make it so that I can assign an ID to each type of Entity, so I can just call CreateNewEntity(int id, Vector2 position). How would I do this? I also have a feeling that I'm designing this badly. Is that true

Comment: In general, inheritance is not a good option for set properties and behaviors. Instead, aggregation is a better way to modeling it. I haven't a good reference to you, so I'm posting a comment. Try to look for "game development inheritance vs aggregation"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you could do this.
You could create an Attribute that will give the type some metadata such as ID
e.g.

```
public class RenderableEntity{
}

[EntityTypeAttribute(Name = "Wizard"]
public class Wizard : RenderableEntity{
}
```

you could then bundle them all in a namespace or a logical container and create the type as follows
pseudo:

```
//Create Entity
//Type Name
string entityName = "Wizard";

//Get the Type
from the namespace where the type has the custom attribute applied to it. Get the type

//Activator.Create(typeof(TheWizardType))
```

The other is that you could just get the Type where the name matches the string you passed into your create method.

Comment: What is the added value of the attribute in this case? Attributes are only looked upon when using Reflection to query a type's metadata. This is considered an expensive operation, why is it needed in this case?

Comment: The use of attributes was merely to point out a viable solution to the problem, there are many solutions to this problem.
The attribute might contain other properties that will identify it as a type of entity that can be created at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Inheriting from a base entity sounds like a good approach. Anything that is shared between all your objects should be in the base entity, and anything that is specific to each type of NPC, should be in their own class. Things that have the same purpose, but different implementation (like AI, or CreateNewEntity) should be marked virtual, so the methods can be called from a list of base entities, but the correct implementation will run. CreateNewEntity should probably be a constructor.

example:

```
public class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; protected set; }
    public Vector2 Position { get; protected set; }
    public int Strength { get; protected set; }
    public Entity(int id, Vector2 position)
    {
        Id = id;
        Position = position;
        Strength = 1;
    }
    public virtual RunAI()
    {
        Position.X = Position.X + 1;
    }
}

public class SuperHero
{
    public SuperHero(int id, Vector2 position) : base (id, position)
    {
        Strength = 20;
    }
    public override void RunAI()
    {
        Position.X = Position.X + 500;
    }
}
```

Comment: I get what your doing here but I want the id to refer to the type of object. So that every time I create an Entity with an ID of 1, it will make a superhero, 2 it will be a spider.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the flyweight pattern would be beneficial here: http://www.primos.com.au/primos/Default.aspx?PageContentID=27&tabid=65

You probably want to differentiate the core state that makes each entity different and then put as much as possible in the shared instance.